# PyDev "New Project" crashes Eclipse

Tags: pydev

I'm a Python and PyDev newbie. My environment is OS X 10.6.11, Eclipse Indigo, PyDev 2.7.1, Python 2.6 and 3.3.

Starting from any perspective (PyDev, Java, others), selecting New->Project->PyDev->PyDev Project results in an endless spinning color beachball. The only way out is to Force Quit Eclipse.

Starting from the PyDev perspective, if I select New->Project, and then select General->Project, the same crash occurs.

My only recourse seems to be to create a generic project from, say, the Java perspective, then right-click the project in the package explorer view and choose PyDev->Set as PyDev Project, then switch to the PyDev perspective, then configure the project folder manually.

Am I missing something in my installation? Is this a known problem with PyDev?

Comment: Might want to include Eclipse tag.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar problem here.  Commenting out in case there's any follow up.
I'm using Kubuntu 15.04, Eclipse 3.8, Python 2.7 and 3.4, and what I assume is PyDev 4.2 or 4.3.

I am also a newbie, trying django framework.  Creating a new PyDev-django project crashes Eclipse.  When opening it again, I cannot continue creating or import it.

Here is some info about the crash, thank you for your help.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc966da042d, pid=9132, tid=140503295805184
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b14) (build 1.7.0_79-b14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.5.6
# Distribution: Ubuntu 15.04, package 7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgobject-2.0.so.0+0x3342d]  g_type_check_instance_is_fundamentally_a+0xd
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```